# How to set site language to be scraped with Python on CentOS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos

My escraper is working perfectly fine on my local computer. However, I have set up a cron so that it is running on my Centos server. But it doesn't work as expected because I need to set the site's language, which must be in Portuguese, but as I'm running from the server with an American IP, I get the site's data in English.

I need to get some books from IMDB: https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=sci-fi&after=WzUwMDYyMCwidHQxNzU1OTA5OCIsMjI1NTFd&explore=title_type,genres&ref_=adv_nxt

But see that you have the option to select the language in the navbar. What is the best way for me to do this with selenium and python ? I need to set it to "Portuguese (Brazil)".

Answer (score 0):

You can try `options.add_argument("--lang=pt-BR")`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--lang=pt-BR")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver",options=options)
driver.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=sci-fi&after=WzUwMDYyMCwidHQxNzU1OTA5OCIsMjI1NTFd&explore=title_type,genres&ref_=adv_nxt')
```